# How to publish iOS app to the apple enterprise account

Tags: ios

Our company recently has purchased an enterprise apple account and I want to create a version of my app to release for our staffs but I can not find any resources about how to publish it? Does some one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Sum it up: you need to create a new provisioning profile that does support in-house or Ad-hoc signing, then export your archived build for a distribution binary.

The answer is quite long and well documented in this document [Distributing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

Cheers, M.

Comment: If you know it's a link-only answer, **don't post it.** It'll only get flagged by someone like me and deleted. This answer does contain detail from the linked page, so it's OK, but make sure that you always include that detail.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm flagging all kinds of non-answers everyday myself, but to be fair, sometimes it's really a waste of good time and even space to copy a long document as an answer. I'm aware of all caveats and short comings of posting a link as answer, but given some documents have a life span of greater that SO itself, it should be OK to post them here. Thanks for the heads up anyway.